# FSL doesn't install on Ubuntu 16.04 from NeuroDebian

Tags: ubuntu, installation, pipe, bioinformatics

I am trying to install `FSL` on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit.

I followed [procedure](http://neuro.debian.net/install_pkg.html?p=fsl-complete) at neurodebian website, selected the correct package, specified ALL software.

When I copy-paste the commands in my terminal the pipe hangs without prompting for my sudo password:

```
wget -O- http://neuro.debian.net/lists/xenial.de-m.full | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neurodebian.sources.list
```

I also tried to separate the pipe in the two commands. The first one runs, the second asks for my password and then hangs. I con't know how to connect their outputs though.

If I use CTRL+Z it stops (of course) and then I type

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 0xA5D32F012649A5A9
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fsl-complete
```

but the package is not found. Also the package `fsl-5.0-complete` is not found.

I tried the mirror in Japan and the mirror in Munich, with no success.
The advice posted in the comments on NeuroDebian just repeats the instructions, and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was probably trivial, but not to unexperienced users like me.
Splitting up the pipe of course didn't work because there was no redirecting of the output.

One just needs to type the pipe as it is, and when it seems to be hanging, type in his/her user password and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the second line of the first command given in the instructions you linked?

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 0xA5D32F012649A5A9
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I did include that line in my commands, I forgot to add it in my post. I'll edit the post