# How to install FSL on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install **FSL** on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit, VMware Fusion.

I followed procedure at neuro_debian website, selected the correct package,
specified ALL software.

```
wget -O- http://neuro.debian.net/lists/xenial.cn-bj1.full | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neurodebian.sources.list
```

If you copy and paste the command to my terminal, it will say "connecting to neuro.debian.net ... connected" without asking for my sudo password.

Is this installed? and then I copy and paste the command to my terminal

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 0xA5D32F012649A5A9
```

terminal said that

```
gpg: requesting key 2649A5A9 from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: key 2649A5A9: "NeuroDebian Archive Key <pkg-exppsy-    maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>" not changed
```

and I type

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fsl-complete
```

but the application and package is not found. also the package **fsl-5.0-complete** is not found.

I just want to install FSL application.

Comment: The sudo command is probably waiting for a password: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660526/fsl-doesnt-install-on-ubuntu-16-04-from-neurodebian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by noting terminal

```
sudo apt-get install fsl
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: `E: Package 'fsl' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick update here:

I am also working with Ubuntu 16.04.

After going (as the original author posted, to: [the fsl instalation page for neuro debian](http://neuro.debian.net/pkgs/fsl-complete.html)

and following the indications there (the wget and so on), I was able to install the software with the originally intended commands*

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install fsl-complete

After that I needed to take care of a final configuration issue:

I had to add:

> . /usr/share/fsl/5.0/etc/fslconf/fsl.sh

To the path (i added it to the ~/.bashrc file in order to get the command )

fsl

to work.

[see this link for details](https://www.researchgate.net/post/FSL_50_GUI_working_fine_but_Command_line_not_working-any_suggestions)

Answer (score 0):

After running `sudo python fsl.py` to install FSL, the solution to get the commands in the PATH is described in [this section of the official documentation](https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FslInstallation/ShellSetup). For example, for BASH, you would need to add the following in your .bashrc:

```
FSLDIR=/usr/local/fsl
. ${FSLDIR}/etc/fslconf/fsl.sh
PATH=${FSLDIR}/bin:${PATH}
export FSLDIR PATH
```

Then open a new console anywhere and if you type `flirt -version` you should see something meaningful.

Comment: @WonsikJung Consider upvoting so that other users can better see this answer ;-)